# C# 4.0: Can I use a Color as an optional parameter with a default value?

Tags: c#, optional-parameters

```
    public void log(String msg, Color c = Color.black)
    {
        loggerText.ForeColor = c;
        loggerText.AppendText("\n" + msg);

    }
```

This results in an error that c must be a compile-time constant.  I've read up on this a little and most examples are dealing with strings and ints.  I've figured out I can use the colorconverter class but I'm not sure it will be very efficient.  Is there a way to just pass a basic color as an optional parameter?

```
    public void log(String msg, String c = "Black")
    {
        ColorConverter conv = new ColorConverter();
        Color color = (Color)conv.ConvertFromString(c);

        loggerText.ForeColor = color;
        loggerText.AppendText("\n" + msg);
    }
```

Answer (score 145, accepted):

I've run into this as well and the only workaround I've found is to use nullables.

```
public void log(String msg, Color? c = null)
{
    loggerText.ForeColor = c ?? Color.Black;
    loggerText.AppendText("\n" + msg);
}
```

Other possible syntax is:

```
loggerText.ForeColor = c.GetValueOrDefault(Color.Black);
```

Comment: You can also use `default(Color)` as a default value - but sometimes this can make it impossible to differentiate a default value from a valid parameter value. Nullable tend to be better in this case.

Comment: @Bushkin: i totally agree with this!

Comment: thx.. solved my issue with color. +1

Comment: works like a charm!

Answer (score 9):

You could check if Color is Color.Empty (which is the default value: `default(Color)`) or use a nullable value and check for null.

```
public void log(String msg, Color? c = null) { ... }
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't specify the colour.  Supply an "error level" instead, and have a mapping between each error level and a colour value.  That way 0 and below could be black, then 1 = amber, >2 = red.  No need to worry about default values and/or not specifying a value.

Comment: +1 Emphasize the what, not the how.

Comment: Completely disagree - apart from not answering the question, this introduces a new semantic "error level" which then makes this method less useful across different applications (what if I want warnings to be orange in one application and yellow in another).

Comment: @Justicle I see what you're saying, but the actual color should be a presentation concern, and this way the *semantics* are the same in every app, even though the presentation of each app might be different (column in a logfile, colour of a UI element, send an email or don't etc).

Answer (score 2):

Usage suggestion:

```
public GraphicsLine(Point startPoint, Point endPoint, Color? color = null, double width = 1.0)
{
    StartPoint = startPoint;
    EndPoint = endPoint;
    Color = color ?? Colors.Black;
    Width = width;
}
```

Comment: Color.Black, not Colors.Black